# How to get the arguments with the spaces from command line in C without garbage

Tags: c, command, arguments, line

I am trying to get the command line arguments to use it in exec 
but my code doesn't work correctly because it returns garbage as output.
(I'm ubuntu user)
Here's what I have done by far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

        char command[1024];
        int i;      
        fflush(stdin); // i try to empty the buffer  

         for ( i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
            strcat(command, argv[i]);
            strcat(command," ") ; //here i try to copy the arguments
        }
            printf("%s\n",command);

    return 0;
    }
```

The output in the terminal after compilation is :

ubuntu-gnome@ubuntu-gnome:~/Desktop$ ./1 theo psallidas
   ����*theo psallidas

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` for one thing you aren't using `stdin`, for another, `fflush` is for *output* streams.

Comment: You don't initialize `command` so its contents are *garbage*. After adding `argv[1]` to the array, its contents are *garbage* + argv[1].

Answer (score 3):

You need a `NUL` terminated string to use `srtcat`:

> The strcat() function shall append a copy of the string pointed to by
>   s2 (including the terminating null byte) to the end of the string
>   pointed to by s1. **The initial byte of s2 overwrites the null byte at
>   the end of s1.** If copying takes place between objects that overlap,
>   the behavior is undefined.

```
char command[1024];
```

should be

```
char command[1024] = "";
```

And `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior (but you don't need this line at all).

Comment: Oh noes! It should be `""`! Or, more efficiently, just `char command[1024]; command[0] = 0;`.